# What is position in terms of a sequence?

Tags: data-structures, position, sequences, rank

I'm trying to learn about the abstract data type "sequences" and am told it has both rank and position. Rank is the number of elements that come before a given element but what's position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ment relative like in a linked list you can only go to the next (or possibly previous) node.

Answer (score 3):

The **position** of an element in a sequence is the index at which that value appears.  For example, in the sequence

```
137 42 13 99 59
```

The number 137 is at index 0, and the number 42 is at index 1.

The **rank** of an element in a sequence is the number of elements in the sequence that the element is bigger than.  Thus in the above sequence 137 has rank 4, 42 has rank 1, etc.  The sequence is sorted when every element's ranks equal to its position.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hmm are you sure? In what I'm reading it says a sequence is a union of a linked list and vector. For linked list the book says "position of an element is defined relatively (i.e., in terms of its neighbors)" and vectors have what you described as position. For example, the list ADT "has first(): Return position of 1st element of S"

Comment: What book is this?  I'm not aware of what list ADT you're talking about.  It's possible that the bookis using a different notation than everyone else.